# How to find which page in DetailsView holds selected GridView row

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, detailsview

I am setting up `HealthMonitoring` and I am writing a couple of pages to manage the event logs.

I have one page which has a `GridView` and another that has a `DetailsView`. The `GridView` has a template button on each row with an onClick event that loads the second page with the `DetailsView` on it.

What I would like to do is; when I click the template button on the `GridView` it then loads the second page with the `DetailsView` and inserts that particular record from the `GridView` into the `DetailsView` table.

The `DetailsView` must have paging enabled. I am stuck trying to find out which page index to load with the right record from the `GridView`. Currently it will just load up the first page index, then I have to click next to the record I need.

Without the paging enabled, I can read my 2 global variables and then load the correct record into the `DetailsView` table, but with paging enabled I'm not sure how to do it.

On the `GridView` page:

```
protected void Details1_ButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //I set 2 global variables here of the selected EventId and 
    //Details to read when the next page loads
    Response.Redirect("ErrorDetails.aspx");
}
```

On the `DetailsView` page.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //without paging I can set the SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand to select 
    //the correct record using one of the global variables
}
```

I have tried to use `DetailsView1_PageIndexChanged`, `DetailsView1_Load` and `Page_Load` to get the value in the first row, but for some reason it is allways a page behind. The variable always shows the ID of the previous page when it loads. I was going to try and keep track of the page for deleting records, but it will not work either.

This is the DataSource and DetailsView in ErrorDetails.aspx:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource 
    ID="SqlDataSource1" 
    runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection %>" 
    ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection.ProviderName %>">
    <DeleteParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="EventId" />
    </DeleteParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>

<asp:DetailsView ID="DetailsView1" runat="server" Height="50px" Width="125px" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataKeyNames="EventId" AutoGenerateRows="False" OnItemDeleted="DetailsView1_ItemDeleted" OnItemDeleting="DetailsView1_ItemDeleting" AllowPaging="True" OnLoad="DetailsView1_Load" OnPageIndexChanged="DetailsView1_PageIndexChanged" OnPageIndexChanging="DetailsView1_PageIndexChanging">
    <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="alt" />
    <Fields>

        <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" />

        <asp:BoundField DataField="EventId" HeaderText="EventId" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="EventTimeUtc" HeaderText="EventTimeUtc" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="EventTime" HeaderText="EventTime" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="EventType" HeaderText="EventType" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="EventSequence" HeaderText="EventSequence" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="EventOccurrence" HeaderText="EventOccurrence" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="EventCode" HeaderText="EventCode" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="EventDetailCode" HeaderText="EventDetailCode" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Message" HeaderText="Message" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ApplicationPath" HeaderText="ApplicationPath" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ApplicationVirtualPath" HeaderText="ApplicationVirtualPath" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="MachineName" HeaderText="MachineName" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="RequestUrl" HeaderText="RequestUrl" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ExceptionType" HeaderText="ExceptionType" />

        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Details">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server">
                    <%= EventVariables.EventDetails %>
                </asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

        <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" />

    </Fields>
    <PagerSettings Mode="NextPreviousFirstLast" />
    <PagerStyle CssClass="pager" />
</asp:DetailsView>
```

This is the DataSource and GirdView from the parent form:

```
<asp:GridView 
        ID="ErrorGrid" 
        runat="server" 
        AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
        DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1"  
        DataKeyNames="EventId"
        OnRowDeleting="ErrorGrid_RowDeleting" 
        AllowPaging="True" 
        AllowSorting="True" 
        Font-Size="Small" 
        CellPadding="10" 
        CellSpacing="1" >
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Delete" OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this record?');" Text="Delete"></asp:LinkButton>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="Details1" Text="Details" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnClick="Details1_ButtonClick" />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="EventId" HeaderText="EventId" SortExpression="EventId" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="EventTime" HeaderText="EventTime" SortExpression="EventTime" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="RequestUrl" HeaderText="RequestUrl" SortExpression="RequestUrl" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ExceptionType" HeaderText="ExceptionType" SortExpression="ExceptionType" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
    <asp:SqlDataSource 
        ID="SqlDataSource1" 
        runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection %>" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [aspnet_WebEvent_Events]" 
        DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [aspnet_WebEvent_Events] WHERE [EventId]=@EventId">
        <DeleteParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="EventId" />
        </DeleteParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: When you talk about paging for the DetailView, that would correspond to the row number in the GridView, right? Or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: @Melanie The GridView has the Paging option enabled also. The GridView right now has 7 pages, with 72 events and 72 pages in the DetailView. So I cannot think of a way to match the page in the DetailView with the page/row in the GridView.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this by doing a calculation. As there is 10 rows per page in the `GridView` I'm able to calculate the page by doing this:

```
EventVariables.EventPage = ((((ErrorGrid.PageIndex + 1) * 10) - 10) + Row.RowIndex);
```

And then loading the page in the `DetailsView` from the variable when it loads.